# Analysis for SFDX Apex || sonarqube Community Edition

Tags: apex, community, salesforce1-app, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Is there a way to support SFDX Apex Analysis with sonarqube Community Edition version 7.2 or above. If not then is there any previous Community version which may support it ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apex is not among the 15 languages [supported with Community Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/community/). And the docs for [SonarQube Apex support](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/apex/) explicity say that

> Apex analysis is available as part of the Enterprise Edition and above.

So they're pretty clear that Apex is not part of the free tier of their freemium model.